# Proving a formula is valid in first-order logic.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm asked to verify the following formula is valid:

$$\exists x (p(x)\implies q(x)) \iff (\forall x [p(x)\implies\exists x \ q(x)])$$

For the first direction, I want to assume that $p(x)\implies q(x)$ is true for some $a$, so $p(a)\implies q(a)$. I don't understand how this implies the RHS however. Take, for instance, $p(x)$ to be false when $x=a$, but true for all other $x$, and $q(x)$ is always false. Then, the LHS would be true, but the RHS would be false. Am I thinking about the problem incorrectly?

Comment: The bracketing has gone awry on the RHS.

Comment: The bracketing is the same as in my problem. The $\forall x$ appears outside the main implication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right; this equivalence does not hold.  And the counterexample you give works.

In fact, we can just consider a domain with just two objects $a$ and $b$, where only $b$ has property $p$, and neither has property $q$.

Then $p(a) \to q(a)$ is true because $p(a)$ is false, and hence $\exists x~( p(x) \to q(x))$ is true.

But $(p(b) \to \exists x~q(x))$ is false, since $p(b)$ is true and $\exists x \ q(x)$ is false. Hence $\forall x~(p(x) \to \exists x~q(x))$ is false.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious that this problem is ill formed or intentionally confusing. Note that $x$ is bound twice in the RHS, once by the "$\forall x$" and again by the "$\exists x$". Since it is bound a second time by the "$\exists x$", that instance of $x$ is independent of the instance bound by the "$\forall x$". So the formula is equivalent to the more transparent

> $\exists x(p(x)\implies q(x))\iff (\forall x[p(x)\implies\exists y q(y)])$

I believe this proposition is false. Suppose $p(x)$ is "$x$ is odd" and that $q(x)$ is "$x \ne x$", The LHS is satisfied for $x=0$ for then $p(x)$ is false so that the implication is true. But on the RHS, if we take $x=1$, then $\exists y p(y)$ must be satisfied, but it cannot be.

Comment: How does this proof make use of the $\forall x$? Or is that component unnecessary?

Comment: This is how I'm trying to think about it. $p(x)\implies q(x)$ is either 1) satisfied or 2) not. If it is, it is because either both $q(a)$ is true or because $p(a)$ is false. If $A=\{a:q(a)=T\}=\emptyset$, but $B=\{b:p(b)=T\}\neq \emptyset$ then the right hand side fails to be true precisely when $x=b$, right? It goes without saying that the RHS is true for all values of $x$ that satisfy the right, but is that all we are trying to prove?

Comment: That's a fair question and I have been sloppy in my solution. Now I believe this proposition is false. Suppose $p(x)$ is "$x$ is odd" and that $q(x)$ is "$x \ne x$", The LHS is satisfied for $x=0$ for then $p(x)$ is false so that the implication is true. But on the RHS, if we take $x=1$, then $\exists y p(y)$ must be satisfied, but it cannot be.

Comment: I think your sets $A$ and $B$ correctly show the fallacy in the proposition and illustrate the general case in the counterexample I presented in my previous comment. I have revised my answer to reflect this. (I assume you meant "$x \in B$" when you said "$x=b$".)